# Полноцветная гиф анимация imagemagick

Tags: bash, imagemagick, termux, imagick

есть алгоритм по созданию качественной гиф анимации, не для вэба. Гиф позволяет показать 256 цветов, зато любых, если очень быстро(30 и более кадров в секунду) показывать разные части изображения по 256 цветов, то на выходе будет полноцвет. Где то в районе 2005 года были программы которые из видео делали гифки по такому принципу, но найти их не удалось.

Итак алгоритм простой.
Распишу для анимации из 4 картинок(кадров) имеющих палитру 4000 цветов и прозрачность.

1. Проанализировать все кадры и найти цвет, которого НЕТ ни в одном из них
2. Заполнить прозрачность на этих кадрах этим цветом
3. Анализ первого кадра, создать из картинки несколько картинок, в каждой из которых 256 цветов(мы разбиваем картинку на "слои" отсекая от неё по 256 цветов в каждый новый слой) для картинки с 4000 цветами это будет 15 картинок по 256 цветов в каждой плюс остаток от картинки. Итого 16 изображений.
4. Анализ второго кадра(то же самое плюс еще 16 изображений)
5. Анализ третьего кадра(то же самое плюс еще 16 изображений)
6. Анализ четвертого кадра(то же самое плюс еще 16 изображений)

итого вместо 4 кадровой полноцветной(apng webp) анимации мы получаем 64 кадра по 256 цветов для гиф анимации

как все эти действия провернуть в магике?

В разных программах и приложениях не то что отсечь слой с 256 цветами, даже определить цвет, которого нет в картинке проблема.

Нужна готовая реализация алгоритма, желательно с комментами, обучение магику по учебнику идёт очень тяжко.